# ¿Es peligroso exponer mi API KEY de Firebase en proyecto Web con el SDK de Javascript? ¿Cómo podría protegerla?

Tags: firebase, seguridad

Este es el código que [indica Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start?hl=es-419) para configurar una App Web que pueda leer datos de Real Time Database con el SDK de Javascript:

```
  // Set the configuration for your app
  // TODO: Replace with your project's config object
  var config = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();
```

Quisiera hacer una implementación de [firebase](/questions/tagged/firebase) en un sitio web con hosting compartido. He probado el código con mis datos y funciona.

Pero como se puede apreciar, **la `APIKEY` del proyecto y la URL de la base de datos quedarían expuestas en el cliente**.

- ¿Esto es peligroso? ¿Qué posibles peligros podría haber?
- ¿Hay alguna forma de evitarlo? (Tendría que usar el SDK de Javascript, no sé usar Node o similares y quiero mostrar los datos en una página web normal que ya existe en Wordpress. Podría hacerlo con PHP, pero no encontré nada sobre PHP en Firebase).

Comment: ¿La API tiene restricciones de URL? (Por ejemplo, solo puede llamarse desde el host xyz, como tienen las APIs de Google o Facebook)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no lo sé. Firebase es Google. No leí o no vi que exista esa posibilidad la cual sería interesante.

Comment: Puede haber ideas opuestas que si es peligro y que no, en todo caso en la [documentación](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions) ofrece algo que podría ayudar en primera instancia sobre la clave API y su seguridad.

Comment: Lo que yo me refería es a lo que se indica en el enlace compartido por @Dev.Joel sobre añadir restricciones a la clave de API para HTTP referrers

Comment: @Dev.Joel has dado en el clavo amigo. Efectivamente, autoricé solamente un dominio a acceder a la API agregando una restricción HTTP [según lo indicado aquí](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#securing_an_api_key) y al tratar de entrar desde otro dominio lo bloquea: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}`.

Comment: Y si sigo intentando, bloquea el acceso a ese dominio por todo el día: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}`

Comment: @A.Cedano perfecto.

Comment: en la documentación de Google plantean también que el único riesgo es cuando tienes el acceso por email y contraseña, ya que pueden crear registros, otros métodos de autenticación no son tan fáciles de abusar y por ende no habría riesgo en exponer la API Key, lamentablemente el Header Referer es algo muy fácil de burlar con un poco de experiencia técnica y acceso a la misma consola del navegador

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El peligro que puede tener es que si tu API está visible, cualquier persona podría copiarla y usarla para hacer peticiones y llegar a tu límite (lo cual implicaría que las peticiones dejarían de funcionar o se te pasaría una factura, dependiendo del tipo de servicio que tengas).

Si es un proyecto privado, puedes (debes) incluir en el contrato que todo el código (incluyendo claves de API) te pertenece y el cliente no lo puede usar. Aunque eso no es tan sencillo cuando es una aplicación abierta a Internet.

Para evitar ese robo de claves, muchas APIs (como por ejemplo las de Google o Facebook) permiten restringir el acceso a una serie de dominios. Entonces si se intenta acceder a la API fuera del host indicado, la petición será rechazada.

En Google (el caso de Firebase que indicas) puedes restringir los HTTP referrers para que sólo se admitan peticiones desde ciertos dominios. Los pasos a seguir para crear una API restringida serían los siguientes:

1. Ve a la [consola de desarrolladores de Google](https://console.developers.google.com/).
2. Pulsa en Credenciales
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Opcional: Si no tienes un proyecto, debes crear uno.
4. Pulsa en el botón de "Crear Credenciales" y selecciona "API Key"
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5. Pulsa en "Restringir Clave"
6. En el menú que te aparece en la siguiente página, selecciona la opción "HTTP Referrers":
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
7. En la caja de texto que aparece abajo, introduce los dominios que quieres que tengan acceso a tu clave de API (puedes usar "expresiones regulares" para incluir múltiples dominios/subdominios)
8. Pulsa en Guardar

Ahora, sólo los dominios especificados en la lista tendrán acceso a tu clave de API.

Puedes dejar la caja de texto vacía para no tener restricciones mientras estás desarrollando y probando tu aplicación, pero es importante añadir una lista de dominios antes de mover la aplicación a producción.

Comment: restringir por el Header Referer es la forma más sencilla de comenzar a evitar el abuso de la API Key por terceros, sin embargo es una medida muy fácil de brincarse con peticiones que no se hagan en el navegador o con extensiones que pueden cambiar los headers, ¿valdría la pena una pregunta con otras ideas al respecto?