# Cómo ocultar una API KEY

Tags: javascript, firebase, api, seguridad, vuejs

Estoy haciendo una app con **VueJS** y **Firebase**, mas sin embargo tengo la configuración de Firebase y su API KEY en un archivo Javascript que importo a mi `App.vue`, y esta subida a un servidor en Netlify.

Pero he buscado en internet y encuentro que esto expone la seguridad de la app, pero no encuentro dónde puedo guardarla. **¿Qué puedo hacer?**

Comment: Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/137881/29967) y la respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro. Yo seguí su consejo, restringiendo el acceso desde la consola de Google a otros dominios distinto del mío (o los míos si fuera necesario). De ese modo, aunque copien tu API KEY no podrán usarla desde otro dominio que no sea el tuyo. El problema es que  si la API KEY está del lado del cliente es imposible ocultarla, otra cosa sería que esté del lado del servidor. Es otra posibilidad, desarrollar la lógica del lado del servidor, haciendo eso, la API KEY no quedaría expuesta.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Es peligroso exponer mi API KEY de Firebase en proyecto Web con el SDK de Javascript? ¿Cómo podría protegerla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137881/es-peligroso-exponer-mi-api-key-de-firebase-en-proyecto-web-con-el-sdk-de-javas)

Comment: Considerando el escenario y la gran similitud que hay con la pregunta y respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro, creo que podríamos cerrar la pregunta como "duplicada"

Comment: ¿tienes autenticación por usuario y contraseña habilitado? Si es así, entonces se puede abusar del API Key aunque la ocultes como lo dice en la respuesta enlazada. Si no es el caso, la documentación de google dice que no habría problema: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#api-keys-for-firebase-are-different