# ¿Cómo evitar publicar credenciales de firebase?

Tags: android, nodejs, firebase, seguridad, firebase-auth

Estoy terminando un proyecto que usa firebase y me surgieron muchas dudas en cuanto a la seguridad.

1- el proyecto se conecta a firebase mediante el uso de dispositivos android y mis dudas son con respecto a las key de googlemaps que van pegadas en el código fuente.
¿Esto es seguro hacerlo de esa forma?

2- Otra duda:
En la documentación  me pide descargar el correspondiente archivo json con la configuración para conectarse a firebase y este mismo va en el directorio de la app.
Esto es seguro que vaya de esa forma ?

3- También estoy haciendo un panel de control web para los datos guardados en la base de datos ,esta parte tiene el login para que personas autorizadas inicien sesión pero mi duda es que según la documentación guardar en un archivo js las credenciales con la configuración para conectarse a firebase y mi duda es que estas credenciales son publicas al subirlas al hosting . busqué soluciones y encontré recomendaciones de restringir  la credencial para que se use solo en el hosting declarado ( el de google) pero en ese caso la credencial seguiría siendo publica.
¿Cuál es la forma correcta de solucionar esto?

Este es el archivo .js con los datos de la base de datos y apikey que quedarian expuestos.

`var firebaseConfig = { apiKey: "api-key", authDomain: "project-id.firebaseapp.com", databaseURL: "project-id.firebaseio.com", projectId: "project-id", storageBucket: "project-id.appspot.com", messagingSenderId: "sender-id", appID: "app-id", };`

Si alguien se quiere contactar conmigo para darme recomendaciones también lo agradecería

Comment: la verdad que firebase se conecta mediante https cuando manda la conexion la conexion es cifrada todos los datos se cifran tus usuarios no mandan realemente las claves al servidor o contraseñas lo que mandan realmente el valor hash que tiene tu clave

Comment: los dueños de firebase son Google son una empresa seria y la seguridad la respalda por los ingenieros de google de verdad no tienes que preocuparte mucho y si es seguro guardar el archivo JSON porque sino me equivoco no son credenciales sino son tokens para que accedas

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Es peligroso exponer mi API KEY de Firebase en proyecto Web con el SDK de Javascript? ¿Cómo podría protegerla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137881/es-peligroso-exponer-mi-api-key-de-firebase-en-proyecto-web-con-el-sdk-de-javas) Revisa la respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro. Si limitas en la consola de Google los dominios desde los cuales se pueden dirigir peticiones no hay riesgo en que la API KEY aparezca en el cliente. Otra opción podría ser hacer las peticiones desde el servidor vía cURL, Firebase tiene una API también para esto.

Comment: Si, se que es una empreda responsable pero mis preguntas son en  referencia a si yo estoy haciendo lo correcto ya que las api key estan publicadas ( en proyecto web ). Quizas te referis a la pregunta numero 1, en ese caso agradesco tu respuesta ya que esa es una de mis dudas

Comment: En cuanto al otro comentario, no responde en su totalidad a mi pregunta ya que ahi la solucion es restringuir el dominio pero la key seguiria expuesta y esa es justamente mi duda en la pregunta 3

Comment: Tal vez si aclaras de que forma tu clave esta expuesta (como dices que pasa en el punto 3) podriamos circunvalar la pregunta a solo esa parte y volver a abrirla.

Comment: En la documentación de Google exponen que solo se puede abusar de la API Key si el proyecto permite ingreso (y por ende, registro) mediante email y contraseña, pero si no es el caso y solo se usan otros tipos de autenticación (SMS/Phone, OAuth), se evita ese riesgo: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#api-keys-for-firebase-are-different así como para web se puede restringir por dominio de las llamadas, puedes restringir por identificador del app para evitar abuso.