# ¿Como evitar publicar credenciales de fiirebase web?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, seguridad, firebase-auth

Estoy haciendo un panel de control web para los datos guardados en la base de datos de firebase. Esta parte tiene el login para que personas autorizadas inicien sesión pero mi duda es que según la documentación hay que guardar en un archivo .js las credenciales con la configuración para conectarse a firebase.

Mi duda es que estas credenciales son públicas y quedarían expuestas en el código al subirlas al hosting.

Busqué soluciones y encontré recomendaciones de restringir la credencial para que se use solo en el hosting declarado (el de google en mi caso) pero en ese caso la credencial seguiría siendo publica y cualquiera podría copiarlas. ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de solucionar esto?

Si alguien se quiere contactar conmigo para darme recomendaciones también lo agradecería

Comment: Como es que quedan publicas? si estan en tu hosting, quien podria acceder? Te referis a la gente de tu hosting?

Comment: ¿Porque vuelves a crear la misma pregunta ?[¿Cómo evitar publicar credenciales de firebase?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/319307/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-publicar-credenciales-de-firebase) Si crees que la respuesta de @A. Cedano no te soluciona tu problema reabre la pregunta no crees otra

Comment: @Capt.Teach no me fije si lo hiciste, pero recuerda en esos casos reportarla como duplicada!

Comment: @gbianchi la reporte como duplicada , pero modifique el mensaje que crea por defecto, sigue contando como reporte ?

Comment: ahh genial.. si, sigue contando...

Comment: Hice un post nuevo porque  al ser asociado con otro post ahi dice que si no resuelve el problema que cree uno nuevo y fue cerrado

Comment: Con respecto a lo que me preguntaron, yo me refiero que al ser publicado en una pagina web o un archivo .js como es mi caso, dicha clave queda expuesta y cualquiera puede copiarla.

Comment: Me refiero a este archivo:  var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "api-key",
  authDomain: "project-id.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://project-id.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "project-id",
  storageBucket: "project-id.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "sender-id",
  appID: "app-id",
};