# Google cloud platform - Problema con la verificación de dominio en la Pantalla de consentimiento de OAuth

Tags: google-api

Hemos desarrollado una app en un proyecto de google cloud platfform, la cual sera utilizada para permitir a los usuarios de nuestra aplicación web, sincronizar sus reservas con sus calendarios de google. Cuando terminamos el desarrollo y quisimos pasar la app a modo producción se hizo necesario enviar la app a verificación. El problema que tenemos actualmente es que en el estado de verificación dice "Pendiente la acción del desarrollador" y en las acciones nos dice que "Debes cumplir con los requisitos de verificación del dominio". Para esta app serian 2 los dominios que tenemos en la lista de dominios autorizados, y ambos ya hicimos el proceso de verificación desde google search console como lo indican en la documentación de google. Pero aun así llevando casi una semana sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje de acción requerida y no tenemos idea de que mas tenemos que hacer para que reconozca los dominios como verificados, o si es que se refiere a otra clase de dominio que no hemos tenido en cuenta.

Asi es como se ve nuestra pantalla de consentimiento
[image: Pantalla de consentimiento]

Y asi es como salen nuestros dominios en search console
[image: Ambos dominios estan verificados con la misma cuenta que es dueña de la app]

Los dominios que tenemos verificados son los que salen en la seccion de "Dominios autorizados"
[image: Estos dominios son los que tenemos verificados.]

Si alguien nos puede dar una luz, quedaría muy agradecido.

Comment: ¿Incluiste los dominios como autorizados en GCP, tal y como se explica en la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/137881/29967)?.

Comment: Si, como se ve en la captura de Dominios autorizados, son 2 los que tenemos en esta sección y estos mismo fueron los que verificamos desde google search console.

Comment: ¿Revisaste las otras partes? Por ejemplo, donde se pone el logo de la App, ¿ahí pusiste un vínculo para la Política de Privacidad y otro para los Términos y Condiciones?

Comment: Según lo indicado en GCP: *Para registrar tu app, deberás comunicar lo siguiente a Google: - Cómo quieres configurar la app, incluido el tipo de usuario y el estado de publicación - El nombre de la app, un correo electrónico de asistencia para usuarios y un logotipo opcional - La página principal de la app, la Política de Privacidad y las Condiciones del Servicio opcionales - A qué datos de los usuarios quieres acceder con los permisos - Un correo electrónico de contacto del desarrollador* ¿Ya indicaste todo eso? Podrás verificarlo en **`Editar App`**

Comment: Efectivamente todo esto ya lo verificamos, redactamos el documento que piden justificando como se utilizara la app, e incluso un video de youtube mostrando el funcionamiento, que hace parte de los requisitos que exige google en la verificación, pero el tema es que dice "Debes cumplir con los requisitos de verificación del dominio" a pesar de que los dominios que tenemos vinculados a la app, ya estan verificados en search console

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar captura de la pantalla `Editar App`, ocultando información sensible?

Comment: También, en Search Console, dinos lo que hay si abres la flecha `>` a la derecha, en `Verificación de la propiedad`, ahí deber decir que se verificó correctamente la propiedad y el dominio en ambos casos (los dos dominios). Verifica también el tema de protocolo `http` y/o `https`, no sea que lo hayas puesto con `http` estando en `https` o viceversa.

Comment: Volvi a crear el proyecto desde 0, tal cual como el original, y esta vez no aparecio la advertencia de dominio no verificado, por lo que no tengo ni idea porque funcionó, pero lo hizo. Agradezco mucho por sus comentarios.